# Is this diagram of the free product of two groups correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-topology, category-theory, universal-property

From Wikipedia:

"In mathematics, specifically group theory, the free product is an operation that takes two groups $G$ and $H$ and constructs a new group $G ∗ H$. The result contains both $G$ and $H$ as subgroups, is generated by the elements of these subgroups, and is the “universal” group having these properties, in the sense that any two homomorphisms from $G$ and $H$ into a group $K$ factor uniquely through a homomorphism from $G ∗ H$ to $K$."

Would this be the correct diagram showing the universal property? I'm most concerned about the red arrows. I am basing my drawing off of the kinds of illustrations I've seen of a product $X \times Y$, so do these red arrows exist and are they analogous to the projection arrows $X \xleftarrow{\pi_1} X \times Y \xrightarrow{\pi_2} Y $ that you see for products? If not, could someone do a quick drawing of the correct diagram for me? I want to put a correct diagram in my Anki cards, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Red arrows should be reversed, since $G$ and $H$ are subgroups of $G*H$, so these maps are inclusions, not projections.

Although it's called free *product*, it's actually [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) in category of groups, dual notion of product. Dual means that if you draw diagram for product $G\times H$, and reverse all the arrows, you'll get diagram for coproduct $G*H$.